# Dynamics CRM Workflow: Verifying that Item is assigned to a User (vs. Team) Before Sending Notification

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

I have reviewed all the past questions as well as scoured google results, but I can't find a good answer to this.

In our MS Dynamics CRM 2016 Cloud implementation, we have added email notifications to the owner of a Lead, or Opportunity, based on certain events.  Sometimes the owner is a Team, and in those cases, we want to avoid sending to the team (it causes the workflow to get stuck in "waiting for retry based on error").

I added a qualification to all the workflows to say: `If OwningUser.PrimaryEmail Contains Data ...`

My theory was that if a user were associated with the Owner field, this would pass (all of our users have primary emails except service accounts), and if a team were associated, it would fail.  However, that is not happening - it is still trying to send the email and failing.

I was concerned that it could be an issue if no user were assigned and the system tried to reference a null value.

However, I can't see another way to do this and no one I've talked to seems to know either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding a condition like this. This should hopefully tell you if the owner is populated with a team record, if not then you are safe to send the email.

[image]